# Sorting string ASC/DSC word by word in a sentence

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i need one program in assembly 8086

input :  one sentence (string)
output :  sort word by word ascending or Descending as user wish

please help

Comment: You will have better luck if you demonstrate some effort on your part. This isn't a free coding service and users here aren't likely going to just paste in a free solution to your problem. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requesting help for homework, it's better to focus on algorithm rather than code.

I assume you are programming in DOS environment, if this is not the case, just translate the concepts to your OS.

The first thing you need to do is asking the user for input. In DOS there are several way to do this, depending on your need you have to choose the one that fits the best. I think a buffered input is the best option here, use `INT 21/AH=0ah`. You can use an online version of the [Ralph Brown Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm) for reference.

One you have a buffer with the input string you need to scan it and recognize the words. Words are separated by specific characters, let's assume only a space (ASCII code 20h) character is used as word separator. You cannot assume that between two consecutive words only a single space appears.
Recognizing the start and the end of words is easy but how do you save a word once you have its start and end?
Words are strings and the problem with strings is that they have variable length, so you cannot copy them in a fixed size buffer and since you will have to swap them in order to sort the words you need to use an indirect layer.
Instead of copying the words from the input string, terminate each word with the DOS string terminator `$` (ASCII code 24h) and save the pointers to their beginnings. Here is an ugly picture of the concept

[image: Example of a tokenized input]

Now you are reduce to the problem of sorting an array of pointers to strings, an easy task.
You first need a string comparator, something like `strcmp`, a function that compare string A and B and return -1 if A < B, 0 if A = B and 1 if A > B. There are many orders on strings, the Lexicographical order is what is intended by the problem. You can find tutorials on this subject all over the internet.
After the comparator you need a sort algorithm, Bubble sort is very inefficient but very easy to implement. The trick here is that you compare the strings but swap the pointers!

Finally you just have to print the string in the order you find them in the array.

I have made a simple DOS COM program that solve you problem. I warn you that you should use it only as a sample, it uses a lot of instructions not present in the original 8086, and I create the input buffer and the array on the stack. Anyway here is its output (in DOSBox) and below the source code (for NASM)

[image]

```
;COM binaries are loaded in a new segment starting at offset 100h
;The area between the start of the segment and the offset 100h is the PSP (Program segment prefix)
org 100h

;Data and code is in one section 
section .text

start:
   ;Set the stack as far away as possible from the code but still in the same segment 
   mov ax, cs
   mov ss, ax
   xor sp, sp

   ;All other segment registers points to CS segment
   push cs
   pop ds
   push es
   pop ds 

   ;Be sure DF is 0
   cld


   mov ah, 09h
   mov dx, strInputSentence
   int 21h

   ;Allocate space for 255 byte buffer (the max) but keep the SP aligned at WORD boundary
   sub sp, 100h
   push 00ffh               ;Push the Buffer structure for INT 21/0ah
   mov WORD [buffer], sp
   ;Get the input string 
   mov dx, sp
   mov ah, 0ah
   int 21h

   ;Reserve an array of 256 WORD
   sub sp, 200h
   mov WORD [tokens], sp

   ;Tokenize the string
   mov bx, WORD [buffer]        
   movzx ax, BYTE [bx+01h]      ;String length
   add bx, 02h                  ;String start

   push ax
   push bx
   push WORD [tokens]           ;Output array
   push 0ffh                    ;Max items in output array
   call tokenize
   mov WORD [tokens_num], ax    ;Words found

   test ax, ax
   jz .no_words

   call show_original
   call show_ascending
   call show_descending

jmp .end

.no_words:
   mov ah, 09h 
   mov dx, strNoWords
   int 21h

.end:   
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h 

strInputSentence    db "Please, type a sentence: ", 24h
buffer              dw 0   
tokens              dw 0   
tokens_num          dw 0
strOriginalOrd      db 0dh, 0ah, "Here are the words as typed: " 
strCRLF             db 0dh, 0ah, 24h
strNoWords          db 0dh, 0ah, "No words typed!", 24h  
strAscendingOrd     db "Here are the words sorted in ascending order:", 0dh, 0ah, 24h  
strDescendingOrd    db "Here are the words sorted in descending order:", 0dh, 0ah, 24h    

show_original:
   mov dx, strOriginalOrd
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h 

   mov si, WORD [tokens]
   mov cx, WORD [tokens_num];

.orig_ord:
   mov dx, WORD [si]
   int 21h 
   mov dx, strCRLF
   int 21h
   add si, 02h 
loop .orig_ord

    ret 


show_ascending:
   mov dx, strAscendingOrd
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h 

   push strcmp
   push WORD [tokens]
   push WORD [tokens_num]
   call bubble_sort

   mov si, WORD [tokens]
   mov cx, WORD [tokens_num];

.asc_ord:
   mov dx, WORD [si]
   int 21h 
   mov dx, strCRLF
   int 21h
   add si, 02h 
loop .asc_ord

   ret 


show_descending:
   mov dx, strDescendingOrd
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h 

   push stricmp
   push WORD [tokens]
   push WORD [tokens_num]
   call bubble_sort

   mov si, WORD [tokens]
   mov cx, WORD [tokens_num];

.asc_ord:
   mov dx, WORD [si]
   int 21h 
   mov dx, strCRLF
   int 21h
   add si, 02h 
loop .asc_ord

   ret 

;Number of char   
;Sentence
;Array of pointers
;Array items
tokenize:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    sub sp, 02h

    push di
    push es
    push cx
    push si
    push bx
    push dx 

    mov dx, WORD [bp+0ah]
    mov cx, WORD [bp+04h]
    mov di, WORD [bp+06h]
    mov si, WORD [bp+08h]
    xor bx, bx

    mov BYTE [bp-02h], 00h  ;Status, 0 = Looking for a word start, 1 = Looking for word end

    ;DX = Character left to parse
    ;CX = Entries available in output array 
    ;DI = Ptr to Output array current entry
    ;SI = Ptr to current char in input string 
    ;BX = Words found

.look_for:
    test cx, cx
    jz .end 

    test dx, dx
    jz .end 

    lodsb
    dec dx

    ;   char is 20h    Status
    ;   0               0     found start 
    ;   0               1     jump back 
    ;   1               0     jump back 
    ;   1               1     found end 

    cmp al, 20h
    sete ah
    xor ah, BYTE [bp-02h]
    jnz .look_for

    ;Change status (0->1, 1->0)
    mov ah, BYTE [bp-02h]
    not ah 
    and ah, 01h 
    mov BYTE [bp-02h], ah
    jnz .found_start

    ;Found word end

    mov BYTE [si-01h], 24h      ;24h terminate the word

jmp .look_for

.found_start:
    ;Found word start 
    lea ax, [si-01h]
    stosw                       ;Save the pointer to the word
    dec cx                      ;Less available entries
    inc bx                      ;One more word found
jmp .look_for 

.end:
    mov BYTE [si], 24h      ;24h terminate last word
    mov ax, bx

    pop dx
    pop bx
    pop si
    pop cx
    pop es
    pop di 

    add sp, 02h

    pop bp
    ret 08h


;string1
;string2
strcmp:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    push si
    push di 
    push bx 

    mov si, WORD [bp+06h]
    mov di, WORD [bp+04h]

.compare:
    lodsb
    mov ah, BYTE [di]
    inc di 

    ;AH = String 2 char
    ;AL = String 1 char

    ;If String1 is ended, check the other string
    cmp al, 24h
    mov bl, ah              ;Value to check as terminator
    mov bh, 0ffh            ;Return value if the other string is not ended
    jz .strend

    ;If String2 is ended, check the other string
    cmp ah, 24h
    mov bl, al              ;Value to check as terminator
    mov bh, 01h             ;Return value if the other string is not ended
    jz .strend 

    ;Compare
    sub al, ah
    jz .compare             ;If equals, repeat
jmp .end                    ;Result is computed, just end

.preend:
    xor al, al              ;Equals

.end:
    pop bx 
    pop di 
    pop si 

    pop bp
    ret 04h 

.strend:
    cmp bl, 24h             ;Other string is ended, too?
    jz .preend              ;Success!

    mov al, bh              ;Return appropriate value
jmp .end 

;Like strcmp but negated
stricmp:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp 

    push WORD [bp+06h]
    push WORD [bp+04h]
    call strcmp 
    neg al 

    pop bp
    ret 04h


;comparer
;array
;elements
bubble_sort:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    sub sp, 02h 

    pusha

    cmp WORD [bp+04h], 2    ;Less than 2 element -> Already ordered
    jb .end

    mov di, WORD [bp+08h]   ;Comparer

.cycle:
    mov BYTE [bp-02h], 00h  ;No swap done
    mov cx, WORD [bp+04h]   ;Elements in array
    mov si, WORD [bp+06h]   ;Array
    dec cx                  ;Elements are compared in pairs

.sort:  
    lodsw
    push ax
    lodsw
    push ax
    call di                 ;Compare current and next string

    sub si, 02h             ;Get back to next string 
    cmp al, 00h
    jg .swap                ;If current > next, swap

.continue:  
    dec cx                  ;Elements left to compare
jnz .sort

    ;If no swap, the array is sorted
    cmp BYTE [bp-02h], 00h
    jne .cycle  

jmp .end

.swap:
    ;Naive swap
    mov ax, WORD [si-02h]
    mov bx, WORD [si]
    mov WORD [si], ax
    mov WORD [si-02h], bx 

    ;At least one swap done
    mov BYTE [bp-02h], 01h

jmp .continue   

.end:   
    popa 

    add sp, 02h 

    pop bp
    ret 06h
```